# Pursuing Masters to get a better job

Tags: masters, job-search, computer-science

I am going to apply for the masters program in computer science to various US based universities. I am  eager to apply to their professional courses which do not have thesis/projects in their curriculum, commonly known as MEng and MCS programs. These courses are more inline with the industry needs and that is where I eventually want to go after graduation.

As an international applicant if I apply to a program stating that I want to get a job in US because of better opportunities and doing masters there would help me in achieving my goal would it be frowned upon by the admission committee? How else can some convince that this is the right program for him?

Comment: Can you please share your views on why is the question downvoted?

Answer (score 3):

> As an international applicant if I apply to a program stating that I want to get a job in US because of better opportunities and doing masters there would help me in achieving my goal would it be frowned upon by the admission committee?

**No.**  That's what professional master's degrees are *for*.

Comment: IMHO, that means it's needless and pointless to say that. So you can spare people reading the application from wasting those valuable seconds.

Answer (score 3):

I can't argue with what JeffE answered, but I would like to add that the reason you mentioned "I want to get a job in US" will be frowned upon by the US embassy if they knew about it, which means that they might not grant you a visa even if you were accepted by a university.

Answer (score 3):

You should maybe steer clear from saying things like "I want to get a job in the US". Rather say you're passionate about computerscience and would like the experience of studying abroad to look at things from a different perspective, or to enrich your culture, etc..

There are plenty of good reasons to study aboard - but already talking about work I'd avoid ;)